# Unable to center a loader on a video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video and i have a loader for the buffer. i cannot seem to center it. Iv tried countless methods iv found online and nothing seems to center it.

I have tried every single method from here: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

I have tried every method from here: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

I have tried every method on here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

No joke im not kidding. i have tried everything.

Nothing is working....

Also on mobile that blue loader ends up at the bottom of the video and not centered meaning i cannot use margins because it needs to be centered for every single screen size. Though the spinner class requires this margin `margin: 100px auto;` or the loader wont show up.....

It needs to have `Position: absolute;` on the parent div.

It also needs to have `display: none;` on the parent div so it is hidden until the javascript calls it. Now No matter what i do i keep getting this:

[Desktop Problem image <--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbEcJ.png)

[Mobile problem image <--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjvyS.png)

The "Hello how are you" is centered. The blue loader is not. The blue loader needs to be centered.

It must work in a grid similar to what i made here: https://jsfiddle.net/9faxe587/2/

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video_1");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder_1");
placeholder_1.style.top = video_1.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder_1.style.left = video_1.offsetLeft + "px";

video_1.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder_1, this);
};
video_1.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder_1, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  background-color: #0080ff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}

.THG-placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.THG-video {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  max-height: 380px;
  max-width: 512px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<video class="THG-video" id="video_1" controls preload="none">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div id="placeholder_1" class="THG-placeholder">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [flexbox](https://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated @DanteTheSmith's fiddle with my solution using Flexbox.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldhoo0f6/5/

```
.THG-placeholder {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display: none; // show with display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: Calc(100% - 36px);
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
 }

 video {
   width: 100%;
 }

 .wrapper {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 460px; // or a percentage or whatever you like
 }
```

### Explanation

There is a wrapper div with `position: relative` around the whole thing, so the absolutely positioned element will be within that div's constraints.
The video is 100% width so it is responsive.
The wrapper div determines the size of the video with `max-width`

The placeholder element has `display: flex` added by js.
It is centred with Flexbox `align-items` and `justify-content`.
The height uses `Calc` to adjust for the height of the video controls - though this might differ depending on the browser (I used Chrome). You could just use 100% if you're not too pedantic.

Flexbox is pretty well supported these days: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```
.spinner {
      margin: 55px auto; // (video height / 2) - (spinner height / 2) 
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
```

If you wanna center the element in entire video box (including the controls)

```
.spinner {
      margin: 32px auto; // (video height - controls height - 45px / 2) - (spinner height / 2) 
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
```

Working with second CSS:

[fidd](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldhoo0f6/)

Comment: That didnt work. As you see im having loads of trouble to center this loader to the video.

Comment: Added a Fiddle, might help you debug further. Is it cause the browser diff? I am on newest Chrome, but might be that other browsers set different defaults to control bar in video or video itself.

Comment: Ok the new edit works though it doesnt center it. I wonder how youtube does it... i am using chrome. Also changing that margin wont work for both mobile and desktop. it must be centered perfectly for both desktop and mobile aswell as any other res. Therefor changing `margin: 45px auto;` wont work for all screen sizes.

Comment: They put the spinner in middle of entire video element (like I did in 1st example) and videos sizes are preset so they know where spinner is exactly per size. BTW in my Fiddle I disabled the video so I can see spinner longer by adding g at the start of video URL. If that is the problem.

Comment: Nothing seeems to work to center this for all screen sizes..... Got any other ideas?

Comment: Use fixed video sizes or diff screen sizes (like 3 for mobile tablet and pc, maybe for for 4k monitors?) - CSS media queries will let you chose dimmensions of videos depending on how big the screen is.  Once you know how big videos are use calculations above to set top margin  for each video size again with CSS media. It should get you to where Youtube is - center of the video element.

Comment: If i use fixed sizes it means if its on a large 4k screen that loader is gonna be half way up the page. Plus i cant test that size. Also for inbetween sizes it makes it difficult to have it centered perfectly.  i need that loader centered. For every screen size. Where there is a will there is a way. Also it needs to work on a grid like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9faxe587/2/